# socket joined the room but doesn't receive events in room

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Socket joins a room on connection, the room name can be found on `rooms` set defined on `socket` itself, but when an event is fired to that room, it doesn't receive that. Can someone figure out the issue with my code?

**Joining**

```js
    this.socketIOServer.on('connect', async (socket: AuthenticatedSocket) => {
      if (socket?.request?.user?.id) {
        await socket.join(socket.request.user.id);
        console.log(socket.rooms); // Set(2) { 'j462VueHBUxufBucAAAB', '62c16b98be39c3605f03fd5a' }
      }
    });
```

**Emitting**

```js
    console.log(
      'Sockets',
      AppointmentsSocketService.server.sockets.sockets.forEach(s => {
        console.log(s.rooms); // Set(2) { 'j462VueHBUxufBucAAAB', '62c16b98be39c3605f03fd5a' } Found in output
      }),
    );

    /* EMIT EVENT TO ROOM */
    AppointmentsSocketService.server
      .to(appointment.patient.id) // id is exactly as room name '62c16b98be39c3605f03fd5a'
      .emit('appointments/status', appointment);

    console.log(
      'Sockets',
      AppointmentsSocketService.server.sockets.sockets.forEach(s => {
        console.log(s.rooms); // Set(2) { 'j462VueHBUxufBucAAAB', '62c16b98be39c3605f03fd5a' } Found in output
      }),
    );
```

I'm testing through postman, & that never receives the response. I also try using Firecamp app as well as wrote dummy script to test - but never received event.

[image: Postman Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The event name on server-side code should be 'connection' instead of 'connect'. Like here  https://socket.io/get-started/chat
Your correct code would be:

**Joining**

```
    this.socketIOServer.on('connection', async (socket: AuthenticatedSocket) => {
      if (socket?.request?.user?.id) {
        await socket.join(socket.request.user.id);
        console.log(socket.rooms); // Set(2) { 'j462VueHBUxufBucAAAB', '62c16b98be39c3605f03fd5a' }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.